# error In select query : Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am using `Access database` ,and trying to fetch data of column of DataType `Yes/No` with value `true` , but its not working, and giving me following error

`Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

below is query

```
cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select TOP " + PageSize + " DoctorID,FirstName&' '&LastName as [Doctor Name],ContactNo_1&' , '&ContactNo_2 as [Contact number],City,Email_ID from Doctor_Master WHERE Display='" + true.ToString() + "' ORDER BY DoctorID", con);
```

How do I check this Value 
`WHERE Display='" + true.ToString() + "'`

Comment: You should be using parameterised queries to start with.

Comment: @Arran Can you please show in code

Comment: What kind of DB you are using and what is the DataType of Display, also use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx)

Comment: @Habib i have mentioned both things in question

Comment: @Durga, I missed it in the question, the better place is to use tags for things like that, I have added `ms-access` tag to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare `string` to a `boolean` thus the type mismatch. So, try removing the single quote from:

```
WHERE Display=" + true.ToString() + ""
```

You could also use Yes instead of True like:

```
WHERE Display= Yes"
```

or again use True

```
WHERE Display= True"
```

and hard coded by the way as Ahmed already suggested.